# How to send HTTP request in LuaJit of the latest version, what library actually works now?

Tags: lua, luajit

I need to send HTTP request in LuaJit `2.0.5`.  I've tried 3 HTTP client libraries so far and none of them worked. I couldn't install the latest one due to an error during installation.

My version of Lua is 5.3

Is there a client HTTP library for LuaJit  `2.0.5` that works **for sure**? One I'll be able **both to install, and to use.**

---

LuaSocket -- doesn't work after installation:

```
luasocket 3.0rc1-2 is now installed in /usr (license: MIT)
```

And

```
$ luajit
LuaJIT 2.0.5 -- Copyright (C) 2005-2017 Mike Pall. http://luajit.org/
JIT: ON CMOV SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 fold cse dce fwd dse narrow loop abc sink fuse
> a1 = require "socket"
error loading module 'socket.core' from file '/usr/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so':
    /usr/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: luaL_setfuncs
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x5617fff23fb0
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/share/lua/5.3/socket.lua:12: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x5617ffed4c00
```

Comment: I'm using [Lua cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3) under Lua 5.1. This is excellently working, but you have to write your own request function.

Comment: @csaar I said - LuaJit

Comment: You seem to be confused about lua versions. LuaJIT is Lua 5.1, not Lua 5.3. Also, with HTTP (and networking in general), your OS is about as important as your Lua version.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see your problem: You really have no idea about Lua versions. LuaJIT = 5.1; it is **NOT** Lua 5.3. You probably have the `LUA_PATH` variable set to Lua 5.3 paths somewhere, instead of `LUA_PATH_5_3`, which you *should* use for that. At this point, I suggest just opening a new question. **your problem is, that LuaJIT is looking for `socket` at the wrong location**

Answer (score 1):

- [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) works on 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3, both Windows and Linux
- [LuaHTTP](https://daurnimator.github.io/lua-http/) works on 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3, but only supports Linux
- [Luvit](http://luvit.io) specifically uses LuaJIT, but you get a separate binary

A quick google search also found [this](https://steve.fi/Software/lua/lua-httpd/), but i have no idea if it works.

---

The problem you're having with LuaSocket is an odd one.

You're not using Lua 5.3, you're using LuaJIT, which is for the most part a rewrite of Lua 5.1; but it's looking for the `socket` package in a 5.3 directory.

This is most likely because you have the `LUA_CPATH` set to the Lua 5.3 include path. This should never be used on systems with more than one installed Lua system, because *all* Lua versions use that environment variable, and it even shadows the version-specific `LUA_CPATH_X_Y` variables in newer versions.

1. Find out the exact values of the environment variables `LUA_CPATH`
2. Ideally, this variable should be unset.
3. If 3. is not the case (which it won't), find out where the variable is set. Common suspects are: project configuration files, your .bashrc and your .profile files (located in your home directory).
4. Fix these variable. Lua 5.3 also uses the variable `LUA_CPATH_5_3`, so you can just change it to that if you don't want to break things.

A quick note: I did not mention `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_PATH_5_3`, because your problem is with a C module; but most likely, you have the same problem with those variables too, so you should follow the same steps for them as well.

Comment: 1) **LuaJit?** No

Comment: 2) Compiles well durining installation? No. The the issues and the closed ones

Comment: 3) I'll try it.

Comment: 1) Yes, actually. 2) Also yes, just not on Windows

Comment: 2) No, it doesn't

Comment: trust me, the best way is to use lua curl, we were searching for about a year. in addition LuaSocket is very outdated, also not correctly working with TLS. we earlier used it in combination with LuaSec, but it wasn't satisfactory.

Comment: @csaar not Lua - LuaJit. the library "luajit requests" implemented upon curl -- doesn't work

Comment: 3) task -- send HTTP request. The library does that, but it also does hundreds of other things. very heavy library, it won't suit me

Comment: 1) doesn't work, see my update

Comment: `LUA_CPATH` is set to Lua 5.3 libraries explicitly in `~/.profile`. I don't have Lua 5.1 installed. What's a solution then? Install Lua 5.1?

Comment: Also, `luarocks path` returns the paths with `5.3`. this is why I added  all of them into `~/.profile`

Comment: LuaJit **doesn't support** Lua 5.3

Comment: `LUA_CPATH` is set to Lua 5.3 libraries explicitly in `~/.profile`. I don't have Lua 5.1 installed. What's a solution then? Install Lua 5.1